# How can I check if an id exists in a document?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a basic chat app and users can block each other. When **user A** blocks **user B**, **user B** is no longer available to send messages.

#### Blocks structure

[image: user-blocks collection]

#### Security rule (conversations)

```
function isBlocked() {
  return !get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user-blocks/$(request.resource.data.receiverId)).data.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);
}
```

So, when **user B** (authenticated user)
sends a message to **user A** (receiver), it shouldn't be allowed to. Because **user A** has blocked **user B**.

#### Problem

The code above is not working. How can I check if **user B** id's does exists in a document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hasAny is documented on a [List](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.List).  It looks like you'll want to move from a field per block, to a single block with a list of ids.  E.g. A document at /user-blocks/, would have blocks = [sender-id1, sender-id2], then your rule would look like   `return !get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user-blocks/$(request.resource.data.receiverId)).data.blocks.hasAny([request.auth.uid]);`

You could also try using the in operator on a [Map](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.Map), e.g. `return !(request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user-blocks/$(request.resource.data.receiverId)).data)`

To combine this with an exists call, you'll want something like:
`

```
if (!exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/user-blocks/$(request.resource.data.receiverId)
     or !(request.auth.uid in get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user-blocks/$(request.resource.data.receiverId)).data))
```

`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What happens when **user B** haven't blocked anyone? In that case, there will be no data in user-blocks. Is that code above going to work?

Comment: If user B hasn't blocked anyone I don't expect you to have a user blocks object.  Which means you'll need an exists() call before your get call.  If you can guarantee the user-blocks document exists, then you can guarantee that the blocks list in that document exists.

Comment: Given that you only have 1 item in your list that you pass to hasAny, you may want to use the `in` operator, since that will probably make your rules clearer.

Comment: I'm going to use `in` operator. But I need to find a solution about the document that might not exists if user hasn't blocked anyone. Can you think of a solution that covers both of the situations?

Comment: Today you'll have to do a call to exists() followed by a call to get().  If the document doesn't exist, then exists() will return false.

Comment: Can I combine those two? Something like this:

`
!get(/databases/$(database)/documents/user-blocks/$(request.resource.data.receiverId)).data.hasAny([request.auth.uid]) || exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/user-blocks/$(request.resource.data.receiverId))
`

Comment: You'll want to reverse your checks to do the exists check before the get.  I updated the answer.